# How to put stamp text inside invoice using css

Tags: javascript, css

I waant to draw the text using css look like stamp as well as figure out at image sample inside (sudah lunas).

css:

```css
.rubber {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px blue, 0 0 0 2px blue inset;  
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 2px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Black Ops One', cursive;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.4;
  width: 155px;
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Black+Ops+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div class="rubber">
  SUDAH LUNAS
</div>

<div>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

Any help please, thanks for advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you could use:
css:

```
.container {
    height: 300px;
    background: none;
    display: flex;
}

.text {
    font-size: 2.5vw;
    transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="text">
      SUDAH LUNAS
   </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
    height: 300px;
    widht: 300px;
    background: grey;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .text {
    font-size: 2.5vw;
    transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
      SUDAH LUNAS
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes you can see at image posted read "SUDAH LUNAS", I want to put that using css without image but text

Comment: I'm sure you can go from here :)

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer but it is not even better, because if I use absolute the text not in auto center of div, those dynamic lenght and width:

```css
.rubber {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px blue, 0 0 0 2px #eaf5ec inset;  
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 2px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Black Ops One', cursive;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.4;
  width: auto;
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  position: absolute;
  top:55px;
  left:55px;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Black+Ops+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
<div class="rubber">
  EXAMPLE TEXT
</div>
```

Comment: Ask this as new question